# Alpha blending, transparence and z-ordering

Tags: opengl, 3d, transparency, alphablending, z-order

I'm making some tests with alpha blending in a projet and I don't understand something.

**In my tests I've done something like that and everything look good**:

- Draw blue box first (**depth test**: true, **blend alpha**: none, **color**: 1, 1, 1, 1)
- Draw left Mario (**depth test**: false, **blend alpha**: true, **color**: 1, 1, 1, 0.8)
- Draw red box (**depth test**: true, **blend alpha**: none, **color**: 1, 1, 1, 1)
- Draw right Mario (**depth test**: false, **blend alpha**: true, **color**: 1, 1, 1, 0.8)

[image]

**Every tutorial say that we should:**

- Draw opaque object first
- Order transparent object back to front then draw them.

Here is the result:

[image]

So, I'm not sure to understand how it work/what is wrong ([I've read this document](https://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/transparency.htm)).

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you disabled depth testing for the transparent objects?

Comment: Some additional consideration on that topic : https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Transparency_Sorting

Answer (score 1):

You typically disable depth *writes* (*e.g.* `glDepthMask (GL_FALSE)`) for the translucent objects, but the depth *test* itself is not something you would disable.

You need to test against the depth values generated by the opaque objects for this to function correctly, otherwise you have to sort ***both*** your opaque and translucent objects (which is exactly what you did originally).